# SQL CASE returning two values

Tags: sql, case

I'm writing my first SQL CASE statement and I have done some research on them. Obviously the actual practice is going to be a little different than what I read because of context and things of that nature. I understand HOW they work. I am just having trouble forming mine correctly. Below is my draft of the SQL statement where I am trying to return two values (Either a code value from version A and it's title or a code value from version B and its title). I've been told that you can't return two values in one CASE statment, but I can't figure out how to rewrite this SQL statement to give me all the values that I need. Is there a way to use a CASE within a CASE (as in a CASE statement for each column)?

P.S. When pasting the code I removed the aliases just to make it more concise for the post

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN codeVersion = A THEN ACode, Title
        ELSE BCode, Title
    END
FROM Code.CodeRef
WHERE ACode=@useCode OR BCode=@useCode
```

Comment: How is title different depending on Acode and Bcode? It is the same, right?

Comment: Yes it is. I just thought that I needed to have it added to both because of the way the case statement is done. I've noticed from the suggestions that is not the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `case` statement can only return one value.  You can easily write what you want as:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN codeVersion = 'A' THEN ACode
             ELSE BCode
        END) as Code, Title
FROM Code.CodeRef
WHERE @useCode in (ACode, BCode);
```

Comment: can you explain the difference in using `IN` vs using `OR` for the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @AtlasBowler: `x in (a, b, c)` is shorthand for `x = a or x = b or x = c`.

Answer (score 0):

A `case` statement can only return a single column. In your scenario, that's all that is needed, as title is used in either outcome:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN codeVersion = "A" THEN ACode, 
        ELSE BCode
    END as Code,
    Title
FROM Code.CodeRef
WHERE ACode=@useCode OR BCode=@useCode
```

If you actually did need to apply the case logic to more than one column, then you'd need to repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I normally use:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN codeVersion = "A" THEN 'ACode'
        WHEN codeVersion = "B" THEN 'BCode'
        ELSE 'Invalid Version'
    END as 'Version',
    Title
FROM Code.CodeRef
WHERE 
CASE
        WHEN codeVersion = "A" THEN ACode
        WHEN codeVersion = "B" THEN BCode
        ELSE 'Invalid Version'
    END = 'Acode'
```

my suggestion uses an alias. note on aliases: unfortunately you can't use the alias 'Version' in a where/group by clause. You have to use the whole case statement again. I believe you can only use an alias in an Order By.